# Comparing Substring Against Multiple Columns

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-like, contains, unpivot

I have a table which has 20 similar text attribute columns, text1..text20.  These columns are of type CLOB.  I am looking to find rows where one of these text attribute columns contain a specific phrase, such as '%unemployed%'.  I need to know 2 things, which rows match, and which column was matched on. I thought I could use ANY as a starting point, but I am having issues.

It appears the ANY statement does NOT work with '%'.  For example,

```
select * from emp where 'BLAKE' = ANY(ename, job); -- Returns Data
```

but

```
select * from emp where '%BLAKE%' = ANY(ename, job) -- No Data Found
```

What would be the proper way to do this?  Pseudo-code would be...

```
Select name, addr, 
which_column_matched(%unemployed%, text1..text20),
text1..text20
from table
where %unemployed% = ANY(text1..text20);
```

Comment: What if multiple columns match?

Comment: LIKE wildcards work with LIKE, only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Oracle, you can use `unpivot` for this. It still requires you to enumerate all the columns, but the syntax is quite neat.

If you want one record for each column that matches:

```
select *
from emp unpivot (col for src in (text1, text2, text3))
where col like '%unemployed%'
```

If you wanted one additional column with the list of matching columns instead, you can aggregate the resultset:

```
select ename, listagg(src, ', ')
from emp unpivot (col for src in (text1, text2, text3))
where col like '%unemployed%'
group by ename
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery to identify the first column that matches and then return that:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             (case when text1 like '%unemployed%' then 'text1'
                   when text2 like '%unemployed%' then 'text2'
                   . . .
                   when text20 like '%unemployed%' then 'text20'
              end) as col_match
      from t
     ) t
where col_match is not null;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm always worried about how Oracle treats `CLOB` data, so here's a test that shows that the Pivot solution should do the trick.

```
drop table emptest;

-- Assuming we are using the venerable EMP table
create table emptest as select * from emp;

alter table emptest add(
  text1 CLOB,
  text2 CLOB,
  text3 CLOB
)
/

declare
  v_text clob;
begin
  -- set one column to a length well beyond 16k but below 32k, max VARCHAR2 for PL/SQL
  v_text := lpad('X', 16000, 'X')||' unemployed ' || lpad('X', 10000, 'X');
  update emptest set text2 = v_text where ename = 'SMITH';
  -- set others to short values
  v_text := 'an unemployed salesman in text 1';
  update emptest set text1 = v_text where ename = 'TURNER';
  v_text := 'an unemployed manager in text 3';
  update emptest set text3 = v_text where ename = 'JONES';
  commit;
end;
/

declare
  v_clob clob;
begin
  -- Set a field to an absurdly long value, with the match value way beyond 32k.
  update emptest set text1 = empty_clob() where ename = 'SMITH' returning text1 into v_clob;
  for i in 1..10000 loop
    dbms_lob.writeappend(v_clob, 36, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890');
  end loop;
  dbms_lob.writeappend(v_clob, 18, 'unemployed manager');
  commit;
end;
/

select empno, ename, clob_name, clob_value, length(clob_value) clob_length
  from emptest unpivot (clob_value for clob_name in (text1, text2, text3))
 where clob_value like '%unemployed%'
/
```

The result of this will be:

```
EMPNO ENAME   CLOB_NAME CLOB_VALUE  CLOB_LENGTH
----- ------- --------- ----------- -----------
7566  JONES   TEXT3     <excluded>  31
7369  SMITH   TEXT1     <excluded>  360018
7369  SMITH   TEXT2     <excluded>  26012
7844  TURNER  TEXT1     <excluded>  32
```

Of key importance is how Oracle handles the `LIKE` keyword when dealing with `TEXT1` for `SMITH`: notice that the column has a length of >360k characters.
Much of the standard syntax we try using with `CLOB` datatypes works only because Oracle coerces the `CLOB` into a `VARCHAR2`, but that has the inherent length limitations.

As this test shows, the `LIKE` comparison does work for fat `CLOB` values--at least in Oracle 12c, where I tested it.

Things will be somewhat different if you try to display the actual content that matches: you will need to familiarize yourself with the `DBMS_LOB` package and its subprograms such as `DBMS_LOB.INSTR` and `DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR` if you are dealing with long `CLOB` values.